# Can I send bitmap file from csharp application to android application over network stream?

Tags: c#, android, serialization, deserialization, inputstream

I am trying to build a remote desktop application. Well I can successfully transfer bitmaps over stream using binaryformatter serialization/deserialization on Csharp Server and Client Applications. But my main goal is to transfer bitmaps over to android application from PC but I can't find any alternative for deserializing stream on Android.

Comment: What is a bitmap file? And why not sending a jpg file? Much less bytes.

Comment: Well with bitmap in csharp you can get a screenshot with like 2 lines of code and with the bitmap library you can do a lot more in less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

If you are using Xamarin forms for android, you can convert stream into bitmap using cSharp.

For native Android you can try,

```
HttpGet httpRequest = null;
try {
   httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
```

You can modify code according to your own.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks! I made some changes in this code and somehow made it to work with both Chsarp Server and Client. I used _Stream.Write()_ and _Stream.CopyTo()_ . `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    stream.CopyTo(ms);
                    byte[] Array = ms.ToArray();
                    Image = ConvertByteArrrayToBitmap(Array);` but the problem now is that I need to close the stream first in order to complete the transaction. Can you help me with that?

Comment: try `GC.Collect(); yourfile.Flush(); yourfile.Dispose();` after every singleton

Comment: No. Doesn't make a difference.